# Загрузка файла вместо просмотра

Tags: php

Имеется кнопка ***скачать*** на клиенте, по нажатию на которую уходит запрос на сервер с целью получения файла для скачивания.

Примерно так:

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'download.php');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ src: '/path/to/image/' }));
```

Передали мы на сервер путь к файлу, который хотим скачать, например.

Теперь на сервере получаем путь и формируем ответ:

```
  $str_json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
  $filename = dirname(__FILE__) . str_replace('/', '\\', $str_json->src);

  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($filename));
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
  readfile($filename);
```

По идее, заголовком `Content-Disposition` мы говорим браузеру, как ему следует обрабатывать содержимое сообщения: не отображать, а  начать скачивание. Но, по какой-то причине, скачивание не начинается, а клиенту от сервера в ответе приходит следущее:

> PNG
>   IHDRÝ¡
>   IDATxìÁA"%A÷@¯A÷?¦ì¥~b|ZéÇ ´H3ÿ÷ÿ·âÇ?þóüúúR?~üøOª¿¾¾Ôÿùÿ¹Ýn?~üøñ£¾ßïÿû¿ÿóëëë8Çãq»Ý*~üøñã?F}¿ßßßß~}}Çq¿ßo·¿UÊªU*«TV¨¬
>   PY ²*@eUÊªU*«TV¨¬ .................

P.s. Аттрибут `download` HTML5 использовать запрещается.

Comment: если ссылку выполнить без ajax, а просто так, то тоже не скачивается?

Comment: А если добавить `header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');`?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, добавлял этот заголовок. Безрезультатно, к сожалению.

Comment: @teran, Вы имеете ввиду, просто ссылке атрибуту href присвоить путь к файлу? Тогда файл откроется в браузере. А мне необходимо, чтобы на стороне сервера решалось, что клиенту необходимо делать с файлом: просматривать или скачивать.

Comment: @UladzislauRadzko Нет. Написать `href="download.php?src=path_to_image"`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, загрузка таким образом прошла. Интересно, почему иное поведение через AJAX?